# position of n highest values in a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[1, 10, 1], [6, 1, 1], [1,1,9]])
```

I'd like to find the position [row index, column index] for the 3 highest values (10, 9 and 6) in the dataframe

expected results is :

```
[[0,1],[2,2],[1,0]]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) with [`Series.nlargest`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.nlargest.html):

```
a = df.stack().nlargest(3).index.tolist()
print (a)
[(0, 1), (2, 2), (1, 0)]
```

If need nested lists:

```
a = list(map(list, df.stack().nlargest(3).index))
print (a)
[[0, 1], [2, 2], [1, 0]]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do the following:

```
df['max'] = df.idxmax(axis=1)
```

this will set a column "max" with the maximum value by column. After that you can get the value using `df.apply` like this:

```
my_list = df.apply(lambda value: [value.name, value['max']], axis=1).to_list()
```

result:

```
[[0, 1], [1, 0], [2, 2]]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `idxmax` method :

```
In [2]: df.idxmax()
Out[2]: 
0 1
1 0
2 2
```

If you want the array with both coordinates:

```py
In [3]: df.idxmax().reset_index().values
Out [3]: 
array([[0, 1], [1, 0], [2, 2]])
```